# div border to flexibly size with absolute positioned images inside, pure css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an editor to animate images. Some images are top level, and some need to be inside a div, as a group, with absolute positioning. The code below "should work"?  It has a bug, do you see what it is?

FYI -- the following text is to satisfy that questions require, more text, than I have above.  So, please let me use that, to ask a side question. In general, I find I have problems sticking borders on things, so for example:
   element.style.border="1px solid red", seems to give me problems, or:
 element.style="border:1px solid red".  Should both of those work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.item {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mouseover { border:1px dashed green; }

</style>
<script>
function id(name) { return document.getElementById(name); }
function fixBorder() {
    var w1 = id("part-1").style.width.replace("px", "");
    var h1 = id("part-1").style.height.replace("px", ""); 
  var l1 = id("part-1").style.left.replace("px", "");
  var t1 = id("part-1").style.top.replace("px", "");

    var w2 = id("part-2").style.width.replace("px", "");
  var h2 = id("part-2").style.height.replace("px", ""); 
  var l1 = id("part-2").style.left.replace("px", "");
  var t1 = id("part-2").style.top.replace("px", "");

  // "math" for the group size and position
  var wOverlay = l2 - w1;
  var hOverlay = t2 - h1;

  var wg = w1 + w2 - wOverlay;
  var hg = h1 + h2 - hOverlay;

  var lg = ( l1 < l2 ) ? l1 : l2;
  var tg = ( h1 < h2 ) ? h1 : h2;

  // ok, now how to I apply that math? is it easy? 
    id('group').onmouseover = function(event) {  
      alert("on mouseover");
    if (! event.shiftKey) elem.classList.add('mouseover'); 
    else elem.classList.remove('mouseover');
  }

  id('group').style.left = lg + "px";
  id('group').style.top = hg + "px";

  id('group').style.width =  width + "px";
  id('group').style.height = height + "px";

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="group" style="border:5px solid red">
  <img id="part-1" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/"> 
  <img id="part-2" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff">  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where can I easily reference online example images?

Comment: if you are looking for dummy images try using https://dummyimage.com

Comment: I rolled back your question. If you disagree with an answer, you can write a friendly comment on it explaining why you disagree and vote down. Please don't bash an answer in your question.

Comment: First off, you are supposed to make an effort of your own, which you haven't (read [ask]), and second, an element with children positioned absolute will collapse to zero height, as absolute elements is taken out of flow.

Comment: Please see basic math for two elements/images, all we need for putting on the order.  And, per other comments, to me, when a question lists "absolute positioning", and the one responding steps on that and takes it off in a different direction, then that slows things down, wasting time.

Comment: @user9008471 Maybe, but you still could express that in friendly terms. The user made a genuine attempt to answer your question, they made a time investment as well.

Comment: @user9008471 You should also take care to not fundamentally change your question after you received an answer. It invalidates the work of others.

Answer (score 1):

You style of `position: absolute;`and `height: auto;` breaks your layout try removing it, so the borders goes all around your parent

you are setting position absolute to all you `item`s this positions all the divs with `class="item"` in the topleft corner, with no height specified whatsoever. your images are shown bigger than the actual div, because they overflow the `div`. but the `div` itself has no `height` set, and thats why you only see your border squished

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .item {
      /*position: absolute;*/
      /*height: auto;*/
      opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="group" class="item" style="border:5px solid green">
      <img id="group-1" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/"> 
      <img id="group-2" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff">  
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```